# How can I place slotted elements into css grid?

Tags: css, css-grid, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

My HTML is like this:

```
<div id="grid-container">
    <slot name="items-to-be-filled"></slot>
</div>
```

I have formatted the above with CSS like this:

```
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
}
```

However, the items that I filled into the slot seem to be out of order. I examined using developer's tool and found out that the slotted items are not being treated as grid items.

Is it possible to treat slotted items just as normal children nodes? Thanks.

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Michael_B, there is no need for javascript in my case, just plain html and css.

Answer (score 1):

The Shadow DOM isolate external from internet CSS styles.
As a consequence, and to be effective, the CSS property `display: grid` should be placed in the Shadow DOM.

```js
host.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
    .innerHTML = 
       `<style>
          #grid-container { display: grid }
        </style> 
        <div id="grid-container">
          <slot></slot>
        </div>`
```

```html
<div id="host">
   <span>one</span>
   <span>two</span>
   <span>three</span>
</div>
```